# Android Layout seemed to be cropped on device and in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout

The Graphical Layout(set to 10.1 1280x800) in Eclipse looks the way I want it to.

But the device(Galaxy Tab 10.1 1280x800) seems to be cropped. I even tried it on a co-workers Asus Transformer(I believe same size as the Galaxy just higher density) and had the same look

I have spent the better part of 2 days trying to figure out what I am doing wrong. I can't seem to find someone having a similar problem. I am downloading the images from a server and displaying from the sdcard. I read that most people are having problems with the images scaling. I could see that being my problem, if it was just the background image was not scaling to fullscreen. My entire layout isn't filling the screen.

Graphical Layout http://www.nickmcgough.com/Eclipse%20screencap.jpg

Galaxy Tab http://www.nickmcgough.com/Galaxy%20Tab%20screencap.jpg

Here is my layout xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="fill"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:maxHeight="320dp"
    android:maxWidth="320dp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/category_list"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/logo" >
</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tagline"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/logo"
    android:ems="10"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="SelectableText" >
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/file_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/tagline"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tagline"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/category_list" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/background"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_bar"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/edit_btn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_up"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:text="@string/editBtn"
        android:width="79dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/menu_btn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_up"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_up"
        android:text="@string/menuBtn"
        android:width="79dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contacts_btn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_up"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_up"
        android:text="@string/contactsBtn"
        android:width="79dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/accounts_btn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="775dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_up"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_up"
        android:text="@string/accountsBtn"
        android:width="79dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_btn"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_up"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/button_up"
        android:text="@string/clearBtn"
        android:width="79dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/email_btn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/email_link_up"
        android:height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/email_link_up"
        android:width="40dp" 
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my manifest xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.ceilink.ulodmedia"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon_144_release">
    <activity
        android:name="com.ceilink.ulodmedia.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="LoginActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="ImageActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="RegionsActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="TOSActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="VideoActivity"></activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: And other than this you are not modifying the layout in the code at all?

Comment: No, I am not modifying it anywhere else.

Comment: I added links to some screen caps. Maybe that will help explain what I am having trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

hope this helps you...

Comment: I went through that documentation before and it didn't help, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

Creating different layouts for different screen devices might help.
Create different layouts for modi, hdpi, xhdpi etc.
Have a look here
https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: You generally don't want to create different layouts for different pixel densities, because you care more about screen size than screen density. Instead, consider layouts for different _smallest widths_. For example, a default layout, another for large modern phones (`res/layout-sw411dp`), another for small tablets (`res/layout-sw600dp`), and a final one for large tablets (`res/layout-sw720dp`).